# Got continuous is not supported error in RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm just trying to do a simple RandomForestRegressor example. But while testing the accuracy I get this error

> ```
> /Users/noppanit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.pyc
> ```
>
> in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
>           177 
>           178     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
>       --> 179     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>           180     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):
>           181         differing_labels = count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)
>
> ```
> /Users/noppanit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.pyc
> ```
>
> in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>            90     if (y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator",
>            91                        "multilabel-sequences"]):
>       ---> 92         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
>            93 
>            94     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:
>
> ```
> ValueError: continuous is not supported
> ```

This is the sample of the data. I can't show the real data.

```
target, func_1, func_2, func_2, ... func_200
float, float, float, float, ... float
```

Here's my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, RandomForestRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree

train = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t')

labels = train.target
train.drop('target', axis=1, inplace=True)
cat = ['cat']
train_cat = pd.get_dummies(train[cat])

train.drop(train[cat], axis=1, inplace=True)
train = np.hstack((train, train_cat))

imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit(train)
train = imp.transform(train)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, labels.values, test_size = 0.2)

clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10)

clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) # This is where I get the error.
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's because [accuracy_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score) is for classification tasks only.
For regression you should use something different, for example:

```
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Where X_test is samples, y_test is corresponding ground truth values. It will compute predictions inside.

Comment: Does anyone know how to compare predictions and test values like classification for regression?

Comment: @Priyansh You compare predictions and test values using R-squared(Co-effecient of Determination) in regression

Answer (score 5):

Since you are doing a regression task, you should be using the metric **R-squared** *(co-effecient of determination)* instead of
**accuracy score** (accuracy score is used for classification problems).

R-squared can be computed by calling [score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score) function provided by RandomForestRegressor, for example:

```
rfr.score(X_test,Y_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

try
`tree_clf.score(x_train, y_train)`

you can't use a confusion matrix either

Comment: Firstly, it is bad practice to evaluate a training on the training dataset. You just evaluate overlearning by doing so. Secondly, once that removed, this answer is just a copy of an existing upvoted answer.